# Can't start test server with python django

Tags: python, django

I'm new to the Django framework and just trying to create a basic website, but when I try to open the server with the python manage.py runserver I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\siuba\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\siuba\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\siuba\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 328, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\siuba\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 60, in execute
    super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\siuba\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 369, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\siuba\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 95, in handle
    self.run(**options)
  File "C:\Users\siuba\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 102, in run
    autoreload.run_with_reloader(self.inner_run, **options)
  File "C:\Users\siuba\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 601, in run_with_reloader
    exit_code = restart_with_reloader()
  File "C:\Users\siuba\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 230, in restart_with_reloader
    p = subprocess.run(args, env=new_environ, close_fds=False)
  File "C:\Users\siuba\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\run\__init__.py", line 145, in __new__
    process = cls.create_process(command, stdin, cwd=cwd, env=env, shell=shell)
  File "C:\Users\siuba\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\run\__init__.py", line 121, in create_process
    shlex.split(command),
  File "C:\Users\siuba\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\shlex.py", line 310, in split
    return list(lex)
  File "C:\Users\siuba\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\shlex.py", line 299, in __next__
    token = self.get_token()
  File "C:\Users\siuba\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\shlex.py", line 109, in get_token
    raw = self.read_token()
  File "C:\Users\siuba\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\shlex.py", line 140, in read_token
    nextchar = self.instream.read(1)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Does anyone know the answer? If so please help!
Thanks

Comment: attach github link of your project

Comment: @ОлегГребчук I created a blank project! Even haven't edited manage.py

Comment: Which Django version are you using?

Comment: @IvanGonzalez Django 3.0.8

Answer (score 0):

Are you following a tutorial? If so, please share it with us. There may be a problem with your python installation. Please delete all python installations on your computer and install the latest version. Then create django project again.